# What is the difference between the core, full, extras and light packages for nginx?

Tags: nginx

[`nginx`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nginx) on Ubuntu is a virtual package provided by one of five packages from the official repositories (at least as of 14.04, defaulting to `nginx-core`, I believe):

```
$ apt-cache depends nginx | tail -n+2 | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -u
 nginx-core
 nginx-extras
 nginx-full
 nginx-light
 nginx-naxsi
```

What is the difference between these packages and what are the recommended use cases for them?

This somewhat old [Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx) has a feature comparison between `extras`, `full`, `light` and `naxsi`, but no mention is made of `core`. How much of it has changed in 14.04?

---

<sup>secondary</sup>
As I understand it, `nginx` doesn't support runtime enabling of modules like Apache does, so would installing `nginx-extras` impact performance?

Comment: Someone seems to have done a more recent version of the feature comparison chart and shared it on Google docs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjuNPnOoex7SdG5fUkhfc3BCSjJQbVVrQTg4UGU2YVE#gid=0

Comment: @StevenKath make a note that THAT document is solely based on Debian.  It does not touch upon nginx-core, and does not include the Unstable changes which remove the naxsi flavor (because it is not trivial to maintain).

Comment: It was a probably a great spreadsheet @StevenK but it no longer exists.

Comment: @tdensmore Wayback link from 2014, if you want to see how it looked: http://web.archive.org/web/20140327063338/https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjuNPnOoex7SdG5fUkhfc3BCSjJQbVVrQTg4UGU2YVE

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> Notice: Debian has adjusted this so flavors no longer exist; this will eventually affect Ubuntu probably in 23.10.

While Steven's answer touches on the key points and a very basic summary of what each flavor is, I'll give you a much larger description of the differences, as I work on the packaging quite a bit, and the very different sets of modules in each is absolutely critical to a good answer.  The basic descriptions don't do much justice to the comparison.  (Also, kudos to Steven quoting my older blog (and even referring to me as a 'maintainer'.  I meant to port the nginx-is-coming-to-main post to my newer blog, but I haven't had the opportunity.)

Also note that the latest packages for the NGINX web server are available in the NGINX PPAs, maintained by myself, based almost entirely off of Debian.  ([Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable) (1.6.2 as of this post); [Mainline PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enginx/+archive/ubuntu/development) (1.7.7 as of this post, with 1.7.8 slated to land on December 4, 2014))

---

#### The Different Flavors of `nginx`:

The different flavors are all the same version of `nginx`, however the flavors were decided upon by the Debian package maintainers in order to provide different feature sets (for `nginx-extras`) as well as the bare minimum and the most feature-effective 'full' set of functions that web servers tend to have used in websites.  The exact reason a feature was chosen over another is not known to me, however in supplementary discussion with one of the Debian maintainers on IRC, a statement was made affirming my initial assessment, that each variant was intended on being a different set of features for a different use case - `light` for a lightweight set of features that meets bare minimum of site hosting, `full` for a more full set of features without including any much-heavier extras, and `extras` for pretty much everything that is in the package that can be included in Ubuntu.  `naxsi`, prior to 15.04, was the Naxsi variant specifically with only the bare minimum of modules in it, as naxsi could be fairly resource intensive.

Supposedly, according to one of the Debian maintainers of NGINX who is regularly coordinating with Upstream NGINX in a private conversation of which I cannot currently post logs, NGINX 2.x is going to have loadable module support.  In which case, `light`, `full`, and `extras` will become metapackages which call upon the individual packages containing each module.  The date this becomes the case is not known, however, nor is which modules will actually be capable of doing this.

As it currently stands, the `nginx` virtual package is designed to just install one of the available versions.  By default, as `nginx-core` is in main and we would love if individuals used it more, `nginx-core` is the first item seen and install-attempted in the virtual package.  (However, the `nginx` package can rely on any one of the flavors of `nginx`, and is mainly there to make installation a little bit easier for those who don't need any specific flavor preference)

A detailed breakdown with the specific modules available in each variant (based off of the [Vivid `debian/control` file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/nginx/vivid/view/head:/debian/control) and the [Trusty `debian/control` file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/nginx/trusty/view/head:/debian/control) (as the Naxsi packages have been removed in Vivid)) is available below.  **Note that this does not reflect the most up to date changes in Ubuntu, and you should refer to those package descriptions to make sure you have updated, accurate information**:

- **`nginx-core`** is the only flavor in the Main section of the Ubuntu Repositories, as of 14.04, and exists *only* in the Ubuntu repositories (and is not in the PPAs or Debian, and is not going to be included in Debian ever).  It is effectively identical to the `nginx-full` flavor, but does not contain any third party modules.  The reasoning behind using `nginx-full` as the base for this variant was that we wanted to provide a relatively-full-fledged set of core modules in the built binaries, while keeping third party modules out at the same time.  As such, it does not contain any of the third-party modules, since the Security Team did a review of the code and found that third party modules have widely varying coding styles which aren't as nicely supported as the nginx-tarball-included modules (this is discussed more in-depth in the [Main Inclusion Request/Report bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1262710), which contains the discussion points and further review discussions as to what could be included in Ubuntu Main for `nginx`).  A full list of the modules enabled here is in the package description, which I've nitpicked here:

  > STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Browser,
  > Charset, Empty GIF, FastCGI, Geo, Gzip, Headers, Index, Limit Requests,
  > Limit Zone, Log, Map, Memcached, Proxy, Referer, Rewrite, SCGI,
  > Split Clients, SSI, Upstream, User ID, UWSGI.
  >
  > OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Addition, Debug, GeoIP, Gzip Precompression, HTTP Sub,
  > Image Filter, IPv6, Real IP, Spdy, SSL, Stub Status, Substitution, WebDAV,
  > XSLT.
  >
  > MAIL MODULES: Mail Core, IMAP, POP3, SMTP, SSL.
- **`nginx-light`** is the lightest flavor of `nginx` available.  It is in the Universe repository and you have to have that enabled to use it.  It does not enable a large amount of the modules available in `-core` or `-full`.  It also contains third-party modules.  The modules available in it are as follows:

  > STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Charset,
  > Empty GIF, FastCGI, Gzip, Headers, Index, Log, Map, Proxy, Rewrite, Upstream.
  >
  > OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Auth Request, Debug, Gzip Precompression, IPv6, Real
  > Ip, SSL, Stub Status.
  >
  > THIRD PARTY MODULES: Echo.
- **`nginx-full`** is one of the more feature-rich flavors of the `nginx` package.  Like its `light` counterpart, it is in the Universe repository.  It enables most of the core included modules that are standard and optional in the from-nginx source tarball, as well as several more third-party modules designed to extend the capabilities of the nginx web server.  It's modules are as follows:

  > STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Browser,
  > Charset, Empty GIF, FastCGI, Geo, Gzip, Headers, Index, Limit Requests,
  > Limit Zone, Log, Map, Memcached, Proxy, Referer, Rewrite, SCGI,
  > Split Clients, SSI, Upstream, User ID, UWSGI.
  >
  > OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Addition, Auth Request, Debug, GeoIP, Gzip
  > Precompression, HTTP Sub, Image Filter, IPv6, Real IP, Spdy, SSL, Stub Status,
  > Substitution, WebDAV, XSLT.
  >
  > MAIL MODULES: Mail Core, IMAP, POP3, SMTP, SSL.
  >
  > THIRD PARTY MODULES: Auth PAM, DAV Ext, Echo, HTTP Substitution Filter,
  > Upstream Fair Queue.
- **`nginx-extras`** is the most feature-rich flavor of the `nginx` package.  And like its `full` and `light` brothers, it too is in the Universe repository.  It enables all of the modules in `nginx-full` but also includes additional modules (such as the Perl module), and many more third-party modules designed to even further extend the capabilities of the nginx web server.  Its full modules list is below:

  > STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Browser,
  > Charset, Empty GIF, FastCGI, Geo, Gzip, Headers, Index, Limit Requests,
  > Limit Zone, Log, Map, Memcached, Proxy, Referer, Rewrite, SCGI,
  > Split Clients, SSI, Upstream, User ID, UWSGI.
  >
  > OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Addition, Auth Request, Debug, Embedded Perl, FLV,
  > GeoIP, Gzip Precompression, Image Filter, IPv6, MP4, Random Index, Real IP,
  > Secure Link, Spdy, SSL, Stub Status, Substitution, WebDAV, XSLT.
  >
  > MAIL MODULES: Mail Core, IMAP, POP3, SMTP, SSL.
  >
  > THIRD PARTY MODULES: Auth PAM, Chunkin, DAV Ext, Echo, Embedded Lua,
  > Fancy Index, HttpHeadersMore, HTTP Substitution Filter, http push,
  > Nginx Development Kit, Upload Progress, Upstream Fair Queue.
- **`nginx-naxsi`** is the variant of nginx which has the Naxsi Web Application Firewall module available.  It too is in Universe, however **this flavor is no longer supported by Debian maintainers, and will be completely dropped from Ubuntu with the 15.04 release.**  In addition to the Naxsi WAF module, it also includes a much lighter set of modules than `nginx-full`. The full list of modules is below:

  > STANDARD HTTP MODULES: Core, Access, Auth Basic, Auto Index, Browser,
  > Charset, Core, Empty GIF, FastCGI, Geo, Gzip, Headers, Index,
  > Limit Requests, Limit Zone, Log, Map, Memcached, Proxy, Referer,
  > Rewrite, Split Clients, SSI, Upstream, User ID.
  >
  > OPTIONAL HTTP MODULES: Debug, IPv6, Real IP, SSL, Stub Status.
  >
  > THIRD PARTY MODULES: Naxsi, Cache Purge, Upstream Fair.

---

## Resource Usage Among the Flavors

While I am not aware of any benchmarks that have been run on the various flavors of `nginx`, it is typically logical to assume that the more feature-enabled the version of `nginx` you use, the more resources it would use.

However, unlike Apache which can be something of a memory whore with the more modules enabled, `nginx` still does not eat as much memory compared to Apache when modules are enabled.  (The exception to this statement is the `naxsi` flavor.  That flavor always eats a lot more resources, as it is a Web Application Firewall as well as a web server.)

I will add benchmarks to this answer if I find them, but again, I am not aware of any existing benchmarks for the various flavors against each other.  And even though the sites I run don't have heavy traffic, I haven't noticed any real performance decrease between `nginx-extras`, `nginx-full`, or `nginx-light` on a PHP-driven site.

Comment: Canonical indeed. This whole question began when I saw this line in my `error.log` after I installed `nginx-extra`: `[info] 19936#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. It's shared and not RSS, but still made me wonder. Hence the performance doubts, but that's secondary.

Comment: @muru the `push` module is well known for using a good bit of shared memory.  To my knowledge (and I may be slightly wrong on this), that shared memory is used across all the sites on the web server where the push module might be used.  However, that module is a third-party module, so any real issues with it should be directed towards their maintainers :)

Comment: Nah, no issues. Do any of the newer versions from your PPA get into `backports`? And since they are presumably built from the same source, a patch applied by the Security team to `nginx-core` would also be available to `-full` and `-extra`, right?

Comment: @muru Unfortunately, the packaging in the versions in the PPAs are done separately from Ubuntu.  Currently, it gets very tricky to backport the package to older releases - it ultimately is done in the PPA because I don't have to mess with merging Debian changes into the Ubuntu changes.  Since the Main Inclusion, I have not investigated backporting, because there would be a lot of changes that would have to be dropped to match what's available in older releases.  (and the naxsi package drops make backporting 15.04 versions impossible now).

Comment: @muru And yes, any patches applied as security updates (or as standard release updates) in 14.04 and later will apply to `nginx-core` as well as the other flavors of `nginx` available in that repository, as they all draw on the same code base.  They just have different `./configure` lines to enable or disable different modules.

Comment: Great news about 2.x. Is any link to the IRC logs of that discussion on use cases, or to the statement that was made available?

Comment: @muru the discussion was not on a publicly logged channel, and I do not have the logs available nor am I allowed to share them (It was on a private nginx team channel that the discussion took place).  I'm seeing if there's a public announcement, but it's no secret that the NGINX upstream devs have been looking into 'loadable module support' (like Apache) for some time.  (There's no public timeline for it that I can find, though)

Comment: I am sorry, I was talking about the discussion on uses cases with Debian maintainers. Should have put that on a different comment.

Comment: @muru same case - it occurred on a semi-private channel as part of the same discussion, without public IRC logs.  I also revised the statement in the answer to be more accurate of what actually transpired - in that they basically affirmed my initial assessment that, for the most part, they wanted to provide multiple variants for the key reason of 'lightweight', 'more features', 'most features and then some', 'naxsi', at the time.  (With the naxsi packages dropped now, of course, 'naxsi' is no longer relevant).

Comment: I think "memory hog" is the phrase you were looking for.

Comment: Very helpful answer, @ThomasWard. For those of us building docker images with nginx, it'd be super helpful to also know what the size implications of these variants are (e.g. what is the size of package + dependents). (I wonder if anyone has that info handy? If I find it sooner I can update this.)

Answer (score 23):

I made some tables based on the descriptions from https://salsa.debian.org/nginx-team/nginx/-/blob/master/debian/control (which, as of writing, was last updated on June 30, 2020).  Given that the tables and the descriptions they're based on are hand-generated, there might be mistakes.

| Standard modules | nginx-core | nginx-full | nginx-light | nginx-extras |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Core | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Access | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Auth Basic | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Auto Index | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Browser | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Empty GIF | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| FastCGI | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Geo | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Limit Connections | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Limit Requests | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Map | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Memcached | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Proxy | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Referer | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Rewrite | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| SCGI | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Split Clients | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| UWSGI | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |

| Optional modules | nginx-core | nginx-full | nginx-light | nginx-extras |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Addition | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Auth Request | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Charset | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| WebDAV | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| FLV |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| GeoIP | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Gunzip | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Gzip | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Gzip Precompression | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Headers | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| HTTP/2 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Image Filter | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Index | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Log | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| MP4 |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Embedded Perl |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Random Index |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Real IP | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Slice | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Secure Link |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| SSI | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| SSL | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| SSL Preread | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Stub Status | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Substitution | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Thread Pool | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Upstream | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| User ID | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| XSLT | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |

| Mail modules | nginx-core | nginx-full | nginx-light | nginx-extras |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mail Core | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Auth HTTP | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Proxy | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| SSL | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| IMAP | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| POP3 | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| SMTP | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |

| Stream | nginx-core | nginx-full | nginx-light | nginx-extras |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stream Core | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| GeoIP | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| GeoIP2 |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |

| Third-party modules | nginx-core | nginx-full | nginx-light | nginx-extras |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Auth PAM |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Cache Purge |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| DAV Ext |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Echo |  | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Fancy Index |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| GeoIP2 |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Headers More |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Embedded Lua |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| HTTP Substitutions |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| Nchan |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Upload Progress |  |  |  | ✔️ |
| Upstream Fair Queue |  | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |

Comment: Could you replace those `X`s to `✔️`? They are misleading.

Comment: @КонстантинВан Done.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 (and possibly earlier, after 18.04), **core** now includes the third-party `GeoIP2` instead of `GeoIP`

Answer (score 17):

Here's a very high-level assessment, based mainly on [the descriptions in the packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/1.6.1-1ubuntu2). (I'm going to fall short of delivering example use cases for each, but I figured this much out to satisfy my curiosity so I may as well contribute it.)

From smallest to largest:

### nginx-light: "basic version"

The minimal set of modules for basic functionality.

### nginx-naxsi: "version with naxsi"

The minimal set, plus the hardened "Nginx Anti Xss & Sql Injection" configuration and its required plugins.

### nginx-core: "core version"

The standard nginx deployment, less the third-party modules.

This is the first Canonical-supported nginx package. It's in the Ubuntu "main" repository instead of the community-supported "universe" repository. See the announcement "nginx-core is now in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 Main!" on [an archive of the maintainer's unofficial (older and now defunct) blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140517213357/http://lordoftime.info/) or on the [copy of the old post on the maintainer's unofficial blog](http://dark-net.net/?p=37):

> none of the already-established flavors of nginx are included in Ubuntu Main (nginx-light, nginx-full, nginx-extras, and nginx-naxsi). The Ubuntu Security Team has said that the third-party modules are wildly different in coding and therefore cannot be supported.
>
> To that end, we created a package called nginx-core which has been included in the Main repository. This package contains only the modules that ship with the stock nginx tarball. We do not include any third-party modules with this package, just the modules that come from NGINX upstream.

### nginx-full: "standard version"

The standard nginx deployment, including frequently-used third-party modules.

### nginx-extras: "extended version"

The standard nginx deployment plus several infrequently-used and largish modules.

Comment: So if I have `core`, the `naxsi` part is covered, right? The third party/first-party distinction is enough to explain the package split, so I suppose a use-case answer would require [sf]-level expertise.

Comment: One thing: as I understand it, `nginx` doesn't support enabling modules like Apache does, so would installing `nginx-extras` might impact performance?

Comment: naxsi is only included in -naxsi and -extras, not -core or -full. Using -extras will probably have performance impacts, certainly more memory consumption than a lighter package.

Comment: This is out of date.  I'll post a more complete statement on this, as I have a lot of influence with regard to the nginx package.

Comment: @ThomasW. Wow, aren't you the dude I quoted above from the "maintainer's blog"?

Comment: @StevenKath Yeppers, and I even touched on that point on my answer.  I had to take the previous blog offline because of Wordpress being an evil piece of framework, but the point still stands.  I'm far from the 'official maintainer' in Ubuntu, but I probably do the most maintenance on the package and am probably considered the 'unofficial maintainer'.